# Print connector was not finalized. Did you forget to close the printer?

Tags: php, laravel, thermal-printer, escpos

Whenever I try to execute the print order function for testing purposes I get the following error

> Print connector was not finalized. Did you forget to close the printer?

My code is below (Laravel)

```
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
public function printorder()
    {
          // $connector = null;
          $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("Black Copper BC-85AC");
          $printer = new Printer($connector);
              try {
          /* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */
          $printer->text("Hello World!");
          $printer->cut();
          $printer->close();
              } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo "Couldn't print to this printer: ". $e -> getMessage();
              }
    }
```

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: **1-** is it shared printer ? **2-** try to use local port like LPT1, COM1, etc **3-** If is it your local printer try also to rename it to something `BlackCopperBC85AC` one word no spaces

Comment: Yes, it is a shared printer, It is working perfectly on localhost, but when the same code is executed on the server, it gives this error "Print connector was not finalized. Did you forget to close the printer?" I have tried COM1 and LPT1 as well

Comment: Well in that case .. you have to use its public IP as mentioned in the doc by using `NetworkPrintConnector` https://github.com/GilbertoEspinoza/escpos-php#using-a-printconnector